# Problem runing 'react-native run-android'

Tags: android, react-native

When i run 'react-native run-android' i get the following problem:

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter() as there is a problem with parameter #21 of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry.
> Cannot create service of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry using ProjectExecutionServices.createReservedFileLocationRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<ReservedFileSystemLocation>.
```

Im using linux as my OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met this. Finally I found that I have installed app in the phone. I solved the problem when i have uninstalled the app and run with different port like:

**Before Uninstall**

1. The emulator is running press CMD + m (Mac) or CTRL + m (Windows). Select Dev Settings and then Debug server host & port for device. Enter the url with the new port(9988).
2. CMD + R or CTRL + R and the application should reload with the new bundle.
3. uninstalled app
4. Run app with this command such as: react-native start --port 9988

Answer (score 1):

You might have the same app installed in the device.
Try deleting the apps with same package name, clear the build folder and then re run again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message. I went to Android studio where I got this error:
 
 `Cannot lock execution history cache`
After searching online i found i had to delete the .lock files in ./gradle.
This failed because it was being used by "Open JDK". So I went to task manager and ended the task. After that I could run my app again.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that problem.

Following are the steps taken to fix the issue:

- Create a new project.
- Copy code from your old project to the new one.
- Try to build it again.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the gradle task is running and you will need to terminate that process.

Stopping the gradle task using the below command worked for me.

```
./gradlew --stop
```